# Trigonometry with quadrilateral and triangles

Tags: trigonometry

> Find the value of $x$
>
> [image]

Here's my solution: Note it is incomplete

$$\begin{align}
X\cos13&=AE\cos15\\
X\cos13&=(AF+AE)\cos15\\
X\cos13&=\left(\frac{1.5}{\sin15} + AE\right)\cos15\\
\end{align}$$

In the above equation, $AE$ is unknown, hence my problem.

Comment: what is the value of the angle $\angle{CAB}$?

Comment: It's 90 degree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have $\angle{BEA}=2^{\circ}$ thus we get $$\frac{\sin(2^{\circ})}{\sin(75^{\circ})}=\frac{1.5}{x}$$

Comment: Got it...thanks